# Plus api deprecated, how to get user info like cover, gender and birthday. Play services 8.4+

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I'm putting the solution I found to help others looking for it.

The first thing to do is follow the google orientation at [Add Google Sign-In to Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/).

Then you have to change the GoogleSignInOptions to:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

If you need to add another scopes you can do it like this:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

And at 'onActivityResult' inside 'if (result.isSuccess()) {' insert this:

```
new requestUserInfoAsync(this /* Context */, acct).execute();
```

and create this method:

```
private static class requestUserInfoAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    // Global instance of the HTTP transport.
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    // Global instance of the JSON factory.
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    private Context context;
    private GoogleSignInAccount acct;

    private String birthdayText;
    private String addressText;
    private String cover;

    public requestUserInfoAsync(Context context, GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        this.context = context;
        this.acct = acct;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // On worker thread
        GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                context, Collections.singleton(Scopes.PROFILE)
        );
        credential.setSelectedAccount(new Account(acct.getEmail(), "com.google"));
        People service = new People.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(context.getString(R.string.app_name) /* whatever you like */)
                .build();

        // All the person details
        try {
            Person meProfile = service.people().get("people/me").execute();

            List<Birthday> birthdays = meProfile.getBirthdays();
            if (birthdays != null && birthdays.size() > 0) {
                Birthday birthday = birthdays.get(0);

                // DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(birthdayDate)
                birthdayText = "";
                try {
                    if (birthday.getDate().getYear() != null) {
                        birthdayText += birthday.getDate().getYear() + " ";
                    }
                    birthdayText += birthday.getDate().getMonth() + " " + birthday.getDate().getDay();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            List<Address> addresses = meProfile.getAddresses();
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                addressText = address.getFormattedValue();
            }

            List<CoverPhoto> coverPhotos = meProfile.getCoverPhotos();
            if (coverPhotos != null && coverPhotos.size() > 0) {
                CoverPhoto coverPhoto = coverPhotos.get(0);
                cover = coverPhoto.getUrl();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        Log.i("TagTag", "birthday: " + birthdayText);
        Log.i("TagTag", "address: " + addressText);
        Log.i("TagTag", "cover: " + cover);
    }
}
```

Using this you can use the methods inside 'Person meProfile' to get other info, but **you can only the get the public info of the user** otherwise it will be null.

**Edit**

In the solution above I used firebase.
If you don't use it, just change the 2nd line of:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken("YOUR APP ID")
        .requestProfile()
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
```

The application id code is at [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com)